# Multiple issues after Debian installaion

Tags: linux, debian, osx, grub

I installed Debian 10 to dual-boot on my Mac mini.

I followed the instructions from the Debian site and I manage to boot into Debian.
However, there is no OSX on Grub and in Debian there are no wifi, which is expected.

As I need to install drivers etc, I get this message if I try to install using the `sudo` command:

```
username is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.
```

Reading online, I believe I need to get into recovery mode, but whenever I select that it loads into rescue mode, which I don't know what to do.

Can anyone help with how to get OSX back on Grub, and how to get into recovery mode and not into rescue mode?

Comment: Regarding sudo: Login as root (you have the password, right?), edit `/etc/sudoers` and add your non-root user. BTW, you can also do that under OS X, it works in exactly the same way. See `man sudoers` for details. Can't help with getting OS X into Grub.

Comment: please remember to use `visudo` to edit `/etc/sudoers` . It ensures correct syntax